# Singleton is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, singleton

We have 2 Singleton:

```js
let Singleton = (() => {
  let instance;

  function init() {
    return instance || (instance = this);
  }
  return init;
})();

let s = new Singleton();
let s2 = new Singleton();

console.log(s == s2);

let Singleton2 = (() => {
  let instance;
  let init = () => {
    return instance || (instance = this);
  }
  return init;
})();

let s1 = new Singleton2();
let s12 = new Singleton2();

console.log(s1 == s12);
```

first one works like it suppose to, but second one give me:
Uncaught TypeError: Singleton2 is not a constructor

can some body tell me why the second Singleton is not a constructor?
thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't use constructor functions for singleton objects anyway. Just write `let s1 = {…}; let s12 = s1;`. Use the IIFE module pattern if you need a private scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on the second one. It treats `this` differently.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: Thank you.
2. Arrow functions cannot be called with new...